# Would the ball hit the ground?

Tags: coriolis-effect

After lunch I normally take the stairs to my office at the fifth floor.
The staircase is open in the middle and you can see right to the ground at level -2 (or -1, that doesn't matter too much) and once when going up the stairs with a colleague we came to talk about how much fun it would be to throw a ball or even better a bouncy ball down there.

We thought about setting up a high speed camera at the bottom to watch the deformation and how to measure how high it bounces back and so on.

However, the next question that came to my mind was the following:

**"Will the ball hit the ground, or will it start to spin and fall into the stairs at the side?"**

Let's say the staircase is 30 Meters deep and the ball has a diameter of 2.5 cm.

Comment: A perfect sphere in still air would hit the ground.  The real-life scenario depends on many factors such as: Are there any air currents? Is the ball misshapen?  How much spin was imparted to the ball when it was released?  Under reasonable assumptions about your stairwell and the ball it will still hit the ground, but the best way to get an answer is just to do the experiment ;).

Comment: hmmm, why can't I edit my own question?

the ball is not perfect but has a more or less rough surface. No intentional spin is given to the ball, but it is released by hand... 
would a larger ball more likely hit the ground or do the opposite?

Comment: A better way to ask the question would be "how *likely* is it that the ball will hit the ground?"  Since your ball will be subjected to many random factors (air currents, unintentional spin, etc), the ball hitting the ground vs. the stairs will be a random event; it could be different every time you perform the experiment.  If you re-cast the question in terms of probability, then you could perform a more rigorous and meaningful statistical analysis.

Comment: [Here's](https://youtu.be/2OSrvzNW9FE) a good video explaining a few effects which might affect your ball's trajectory. You have wind (or slight air current changes indoors) which will obviously push your ball around and you have the Magnus effect which will cause the ball to deviate from its path if it has any spin.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I saw this video first before or after the question came to my mind. In engineering SE I wanted to tag it with "Magnus effect" but was not permitted to create a new tag...
This is exactly what I was thinking about when posting the question! Let's keep wind and current out of the focus: will the unintentional spin be sufficient to alter the balls curve sufficiently?